# What is the expected total number of topological sorts in a Directed a cyclic graph with $n$ vertices?

Tags: probability, graph-theory, order-theory, random-graphs, directed-graphs

I know that a DAG with $n$ vertices can have $O(n!)$ topological sorts. However, I am interested in knowing the **expected** number of topological sorts in a randomly generated DAG?

Comment: Please elaborate the generating procedure of your DAG.

Comment: @expiTTp1z0 Lets say if $n=4$. I let the probability that node $i$ is connected to node $j$ as $p=\log(n)/n=\log(4)/4$. Then I keep generating edges randomly from node $i$ to nodes $i+1, ...,n$ according to the probability. So node $i$ and $j, i<j$ have probability of being connected as $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of time and effort of research, I've found my answer.

In a paper published by Graham Brightwell [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnVaE.png), he showed that the average number of linear extensions (topological sorts) for a partial order (DAG) $A_n$ is given by the following asymptotic functions:

[image]

It's worth noting that the average number is still of O(n!) in magnitude which I find very interesting. In other words, on average, your DAG will have A LOT of topological sorts. It's not just the worst case that is $O(n!)$

[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnVaE.png)] [The Average Number of Linear Extensions of
a Partial Order](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S009731659680001X/1-s2.0-S009731659680001X-main.pdf?_tid=60193c36-6aac-11e7-8768-00000aacb360&acdnat=1500267604_1cc4f55ca8df61f00ebacdb2371885f4)